# where clause selecting term codes

Tags: sql, oracle

I am making a report to select some data regarding students, and using the term code they are in which corresponds with their GPA term code.

Our term codes work like this: 201410 is spring 201450 is summer 201480 is fall. I need to see their previous semesters GPA (as this current semester isn't finished) I am writing a case statement to signify this but am not having much luck.

If the term code is in a 10 semester I want to select the previous fall semester, etc. Any help or tips would be appreciated.

```
and TERM_CODE = :parm_DD_TermCode.TERM_CODE
and (CASE
      WHEN TERM_CODE LIKE '%%%%80'
           THEN GPA_TERM_CODE = (SUBSTR(:parm_DD_TermCode.TERM_CODE,1,4)||'50')
      WHEN TERM_CODE LIKE '%%%%50'
           THEN GPA_TERM_CODE = (SUBSTR(:parm_DD_TermCode.TERM_CODE,1,4)||'10')
      WHEN TERM_CODE LIKE '%%%%10'
           THEN GPA_TERM_CODE = (SUBSTR(:parm_DD_TermCode.TERM_CODE,1,4)-1||'80')
      END)
```

Comment: `'%80'` will suffice... % is a wildcard that doesn't neccessarily mean a single wildcard char, % could mean 2014. If you wanted to there is another wildcard `_` that is a wildcard replacement for exactly one char, so `2014__`

Comment: It looks like a trigger, can you post the rest of it, because i don't understand this code situation. Thanks

Comment: I suggest to use LAG function if it is possible and I understood your situation. This function returns previous value in query.

Comment: @DARK_A I also think in analytic functions, but note the case is inside a condition, you can't use LAG function there, that's why i ask for complete code

Comment: I have never heard of a lag function until just now.. seems interesting. J-Dizzle thank you for your input that will most likely work (I am getting a missing keyword error now..) Aramillo the rest of my code is just selecting names and joining tables thus far.. nothing to really deal with this section :)

Comment: @Aramillo I saw case, but I assume it is used just to get previous value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know there is no boolean type in Oracle SQL, so you cannot have a `CASE` expression that evaluates to a boolean value. Fortunately, in your particular case you don't need it:

```
and TERM_CODE = :parm_DD_TermCode.TERM_CODE
and GPA_TERM_CODE = CASE
  WHEN TERM_CODE LIKE '%80'
       THEN SUBSTR(:parm_DD_TermCode.TERM_CODE, 1, 4) || '50'
  WHEN TERM_CODE LIKE '%50'
       THEN SUBSTR(:parm_DD_TermCode.TERM_CODE, 1, 4) || '10'
  WHEN TERM_CODE LIKE '%10'
       THEN to_char(to_number(SUBSTR(:parm_DD_TermCode.TERM_CODE, 1, 4)) - 1) || '80'
  END
```

As you can see, I also have added some explicit type conversions: trusting SQL implicit conversions is a **SPECIALLY BAD IDEA**. The code above assumes that `TERM_CODE` and `GPA_TERM_CODE` are strings.

Comment: Thanks I was just thinking I should use a case for the GPA_TERM_CODE itself, the implicit conversions is something I would need to watch out for as well Thank you