# SQL statement with different scenarios in the WHERE clause

Tags: sql

I'm trying to write a query which has an input parameter that is optional. If the parameter is left empty, I have to select every single record from a table. If the parameter is not empty though, I have to filter only by the provided values in it. My idea is to use a `CASE` statement but for some reason I always get empty result set no matter what I put in the `@list` variable. Any better ideas?

```
SELECT * FROM my_tables
WHERE column_one IN (
    CASE
        WHEN LEN(@list) > 0 THEN @list
        ELSE (SELECT column_one FROM my_table) END
)
```

Comment: Case _expression_.

Comment: It's generally better to use AND/OR instead of CASE in WHERE and ON clauses.

Comment: I had a similar-esque question. Please check the responses I got here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25872970/where-clause-selecting-term-codes

Comment: What kind of datatype is `@list` parameter, what `DBMS` are you using, how do you call the query. Provide more details.

Answer (score 1):

Write 2 different SQL for the two case and UNION them. Only one query will provide result the other one will always provide empty resultset. Something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM my_tables
WHERE LEN(@list) > 0 and column_one IN (@list)

UNION

SELECT * FROM my_tables
WHERE LEN(@list) = 0 and column_one IN (SELECT column_one FROM my_table)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
SELECT * FROM my_tables
WHERE 
    (LEN(@list) > 0 AND column_one = @list)
    OR (LEN(@list) = 0 AND column_one IN (SELECT column_one FROM my_table))
```